# Is there another Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-physics

We all know of other languages, Spanish, English, Frensh, German...

...**but** **is there** **another** way to quantify and Analyse the world than **Mathematics** (in our age) ?

Comment: You've won the 'most bizarre question of 2016' award. Congrats.

Comment: sure, with opinions. but opinions never built anything.

Comment: Your question cannot have a mathematical answer (do you see why?), so it is not a mathematical question and is not in scope in MSE.

Comment: The equivalent of "Is there another mathematics" would be "Is there another Language" where Language means the concept of language itself.  Different languages would be more like different areas of mathematics or different notations (or even doing mathematics in German vs Russian vs English)

Comment: I don't understand well your question, but I want to do feedback about a possible interpretation of your question: you can see for example the Wikipedia article for *Max Tegmark*, and the related *Mathematical universe hypothesis*. I hope that it is useful about your question if this article are interesting  for you, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is, maybe there isn't – but there are different areas of mathematics to quantify and analyse the world. There are even different systems of mathematics, ones different from that based on the axioms of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory most commonly used in our age. One professor of mathematics has even attempted to redevelop the whole foundation of mathematics without conventional set theory, in particular the theory of infinite sets and real numbers, which he claims contain "logical flaws". His name is Norman J. Wildberger; he works at the University of New South Wales, Australia, and he even has a series of [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/user/njwildberger/playlists) of over 200 videos devoted to expounded his "rational mathematics".

Answer (score 3):

Mathematics relies on axioms (propositions we start with) and rules of inference (which determine how we can expand the list of "proven" propositions), but there is variation in the axioms and inference rules adopted.

For example, mathematicians often take set theory as the base of the subject, but even if they do there are many set theories (ZFC, NBG, NF etc.). At a higher level there are multiple number systems, multiple geometries, multiple algebraic structures...

There are also many logics (classical, intuitionistic, dual-intuitionistic, quantum...), all with their own inference rules.

There is "one mathematics" in the sense of an umbrella over all the "this implies that" studies, but there are many different choices of "this".